# How do I make VoiceOver read paragraphs in InDesign-created PDF without pausing on each line?

Tags: pdf, accessibility, acrobat, adobe-indesign, voiceover

I created a PDF using InDesign according to instructions from Adobe tutorials. I tagged the elements properly, using Articles etc, and exported the document to PDF.

When I check the PDF using Preview on Mac, VoiceOver reads the paragraph content continuously. But when I open the PDF in Acrobat Reader, and then use VoiceOver, it reads the text line by line, stopping at the end of the lines. I have to use ctrl-option-rightarrow to move to the next line.

Is there something that I didn't do in InDesign? The paragraphs are just simple paragraphs. They are styled, and tagged properly. Any ideas?